# Python dictConfig time rotation not working

Tags: python, logging

I want daily rotation logs.
I set this dictConfig and this config creates log file

> dinfo.log

but not rotating it even after I waited 1 day.
What's wrong?

```
'info_time_handler': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        "when": "d",  # rotate daily
        "interval": 1,
        "backupCount": 7,
        'filename': '../logs/dinfo.log',
        'backupCount': 7,
        'encoding': 'utf8'
    },
```

adding whole config
This info_file_handler works well,but info_time_handler not rotating and not logging except that applications is started and mothing more that exists in console handler.

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
    },

    'info_file_handler': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'filename': '../logs/info.log',
        'maxBytes': 10485760,
        'backupCount': 20,
        'encoding': 'utf8'
    },

    'error_file_handler': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'filename': '../logs/errors.log',
        'maxBytes': 10485760,
        'backupCount': 20,
        'encoding': 'utf8'
    },

    'info_time_handler': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        "when": "d",  # rotate daily
        "interval": 1,
        "backupCount": 7,
        'filename': '../logs/dinfo.log',
        'backupCount': 7,
        'encoding': 'utf8'
    },

    'error_time_handler': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        "when": "d",  # rotate daily
        "interval": 1,
        "backupCount": 7,
        'filename': '../logs/dinfo.log',
        'backupCount': 7,
        'encoding': 'utf8'
    }
},
'root': {
    'level': 'INFO',
    'handlers': ['console', 'info_time_handler', 'error_time_handler']
}  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotation only happens when you actually log an event and it gets to the handler. So if you have a long-lived process that doesn't log at `INFO` (the level you set in your snippet) or above regularly, then you may not see rollover until that happens. You waited a day, but did something get logged at `INFO` or higher on the next day?

Comment: Yes a lot which I see in console handler ,info_time_handler dinfo.log have logs only about that app is started.